# JFrame not working properly when I use methods to change its elements

Tags: java, methods, jframe, outer-join, alter

I'm pretty new at Java and doing a basic college project. So I first made this class called ScreenDefiner, with an initialized JFrame called mainscreen as a field, and some JButtons and a JLabel (to set the background image), and other irrelevant stuff. Then I made a method called initializeScreen to set the JFrame's main properties, which would never change. Then another method, setScreenBeginning, which would add the buttons to mainscreen and change them, same with any other element in mainscreen that I wanted to change. The idea was to use various setScreen[something] to change what the user sees. But this really isn't working properly. I can't really describe what is happening, it's just bugging pretty hard. The screenshot below shows the most basic error: setScreenBeginning not making anything visible, but still changing the background (so the screenbg.setIcon line inside it must be working... right? Why isn't anything else working then?)

Btw, it works pretty well if I'm initializing and changing the interface in the same method, but my professor wouldn't like that (would be a gigantic method). So I guess there's some java definition/limitation that I don't know of and that keeps me from altering that stuff with outer methods?

Anyone who helps will get sent a photo of a happy strawberry.

The fail:
[image]

This is the code(I'm importing javax.swing.* and java.awt.*, but I couldn't paste that part here, guess I'm just a bit tired already):

```
public class ScreenDefiner {
JFrame mframe = new JFrame();
JLabel screenbg = new JLabel();
JButton pickClassButton = new JButton();
JButton pickClassBrute = new JButton();
JButton pickClassDetective = new JButton();
JButton pickStats = new JButton();
JButton start = new JButton();
JButton help = new JButton();

public void initializeScreen(){

    screenbg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    mframe.setSize(1280, 720);
    mframe.setLayout(null);
    mframe.setVisible(true);
    mframe.setResizable(false);
    mframe.setContentPane(screenbg);
    mframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public void setScreenBeginning() {

    screenbg.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\projectScrewed\\media\\images\\startscreen\\bg_basic.png"));

    pickClassButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\projectScrewed\\media\\images\\startscreen\\button_pickclass.png"));
    pickClassBrute.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\projectScrewed\\media\\images\\startscreen\\button_brute.png"));
    pickClassDetective.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\projectScrewed\\media\\images\\startscreen\\button_detective.png"));
    help.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\projectScrewed\\media\\images\\startscreen\\button_help.png"));
    pickStats.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\projectScrewed\\media\\images\\startscreen\\button_pickstats.png"));
    start.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\projectScrewed\\media\\images\\startscreen\\button_start.png"));

    pickClassButton.setEnabled(true);
    pickClassBrute.setEnabled(false);
    pickClassDetective.setEnabled(false);
    help.setEnabled(true);
    pickStats.setEnabled(false);
    start.setEnabled(true);

    pickClassButton.setVisible(true);
    pickClassBrute.setVisible(false);
    pickClassDetective.setVisible(false);
    help.setVisible(true);
    pickStats.setVisible(false);
    start.setVisible(false);

    pickClassButton.setBounds(970, 159, 200, 96);
    pickClassBrute.setBounds(970, 255, 200, 96);
    pickClassDetective.setBounds(970, 351, 200, 96);
    help.setBounds(970, 447, 200, 96);
    pickStats.setBounds(970, 159, 200, 96);
    start.setBounds(970, 159, 200, 96);

    mframe.add(pickClassButton);
    mframe.add(pickClassBrute);
    mframe.add(pickClassDetective);
    mframe.add(help);
    mframe.add(pickStats);
    mframe.add(start);

}


public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScreenDefiner mainWindow = new ScreenDefiner();
    mainWindow.initializeScreen();
    mainWindow.setScreenBeginning();
}
```

Comment: Several issues are immediately apparent, starting with `setLayout(null)` (you want to avoid this if at all possible) and then moving to calling `setVisible(true)` prior to adding any components to the GUI, so the components won't show.

Comment: Ok, I'll get rid of the setLayout(null). Can you say why I should avoid it though? As for putting the add commands ahead, yea, that worked, thanks! Can you see any other issues? Any reason why that uh... structure wouldn't work later on? Or is the idea OK? And should any of those fields be made private? Sorry for asking so many questions, I'm still really bad at programming

Comment: While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: Note that you're far better off learning about and using the layout managers. You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing). Note that you can nest JPanels, each using its own simple layout.

Comment: I'll try that, I'm not sure I'd have enough time though. Or if the professor would accept, since he didn't teach about layout managers (he probably would, but he's picky sometimes). But if it's better I'll definitely find some time to learn it. For now I'll get around the appearance issues by setting the JFrame to non-resizable if there isn't any serious problem with it (is there?)

Does the order of adding matter? For some reason if I swap the order the screen gets all bugged. Like this: https://puu.sh/vkfxw/68b3c8939f.png (the activated button is pretty fitting to the situation...)

Comment: I only altered the three last ones, which went help, pickStats, start, and worked fine. But when I altered them to pickStats, start, help, the screen became what's in that screenshot. What gives?

Comment: If you want to have an image behind the components, then don't use a JLabel but rather create a JPanel, override its paintComponent method and draw your image there. Then add your components to this same JPanel and add the JPanel to the JFrame's contentPane. This is well described in many questions and answers on this site.